# ActiveRecord, has_many, polymorphic and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've came into a problem while working with AR and polymorphic, here's the description,

`class Base < ActiveRecord::Base; end` 
`class Subscription < Base`

> `set_table_name :subscriptions` 
>   `has_many :posts, :as => :subscriptable`

`end`

`class Post < ActiveRecord::Base`

> `belongs_to :subscriptable, :polymorphic => true`

`end`

in the console,

`>> s = Subscription.create(:name => 'test')`
`>> s.posts.create(:name => 'foo', :body => 'bar')`

and it created a `Post` like: 
`#<Post id: 1, name: "foo", body: "bar", subscriptable_type: "Base", subscriptable_id: 1, created_at: "2010-05-10 12:30:10", updated_at: "2010-05-10 12:30:10">`

the `subscriptable_type` is `Base` but `Subscription`, anybody can give me a hand on this?

Comment: The class Base has its own table or is it an abstract class?

Comment: @Vlad Zloeanu, the class Base does not have its own table, it's just a child of ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class `Base` is an abstract model, you have to specify that in the model definition:

```
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your subscriptions table have a 'type' column?  I'm guessing that Rails thinks that Base/Subscription are STI models.  So when a row is retrieved from the subscriptions table and no 'type' column is present, it just defaults to the parent class of Base.  Just a guess...

Comment: I added a column named 'type' to `Subscription`, and created a post with it, no luck, the subscriptable_type is still `Base` but `Subscription`